# R: Save All the Code That You Entered in a Session

Tags: r, save, rstudio

I am working with the R programming language (r studio). I entered a lot of code in my session. Is there a quick way to save or export all the code that you enter in R? I tried to manually copy and paste all the code into a notepad file, but so much code was entered that I can't when I try to scroll up and copy it - it stops appearing on the screen.

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: See the `savehistory()` function.

Comment: thank you for your answer! you answered here first, I would have "checked the check mark" for your question but you left it in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto about savehistory(). And if you want to just save your code you can save it to a .R file using the RStudio file system. Then you can open that file in notepad or whatever if you want to. Also, when you close RStudio, it will ask if you want to save the workspace which is everything from your session saved into .Rhistory file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use savehistory(). If you're using Linux (unsure about Windows), it's already in a file in your home folder called .Rhistory, which is saved automatically if you click "save workspace" when you exit RStudio.

See this link for more information: https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-save-the-history-of-your-work-in-r/

Comment: thank you! i cant believe how well this works!